# Can collectd behave as a nagios alternative?

Tags: nagios, collectd

Collectd provides a great way to measure machine stats. What if I need to extend the plugin system to support

1. Configuration of the machine being measured
2. List of all processes running on the server with utilization rates for cpu, memory and disk?
3. Scan for security vulnerabilities?
4. Patch management - if collectd client need to be upgraded  users now will need to recompile and reinstall. Can we push a upgrade to all client machines running collectd agents? My guess is it should be possible since server and client are in multicast mode in UDP (there is no client server mode right?)

I currently have graphite setup for graphs and mongodb to collect the data. Ideally I want to store non numerical data in mongodb.

Is the item 1, 2 and 3 possible?

Answer (score 1):

- 1  no.
- 2 not really. However if you use the `/processes/` plugin, you will be able to track the process list at all times, for instance using the `/unixsock/` plugin. You do have non-numerical data to some extent in the form of tags contained in plugin/instance/type/instance.
- 3 no.
- 4 no, however you're not bound to use multicast, the `/network/` plugin can handle unicast traffic.